# Agrupar en Sql Server y realizar sumas por agrupacion

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Estimados espero me puedan orientar estoy realizando una consulta en sql server, tengo que agrupar por numero de factura y que esten ordenados por fecha de la mas antigua a la fecha actual.

Realize una tabla temporal, luego mi select le agregue un union all para que me realize la suma de cada agrupacion, el problema que tengo que realiza la suma pero no en la fila de abajo de cada grupo.

Me podrian orientar como puede realizar dicha accion.

Dejo el codigo que utilizo.

```
DECLARE @tbTemp TABLE
                  (
                    "Fecha factura"                 DATE,
                    "Numero factura"                VARCHAR(200),
                    "Paciente"                      VARCHAR(200),
                    "Cliente"                       VARCHAR(200),
                    "Tarifa"                        VARCHAR(300),
                    "Servicio"                      VARCHAR(300),
                    "Total importe"                 NUMERIC(16,2)

                   )
INSERT INTO @tbTemp(
                    "Fecha factura",
                    "Numero factura",
                    "Paciente",
                    "Cliente",
                    "Tarifa",
                    "Servicio",
                    "Total importe"
)

select 
[Fecha factura],
[Numero factura], 
Paciente as [Paciente], 
Cliente as [Cliente], 
Tarifa,
Servicio,
[Total importe]

from VLISE_Cobros_por_linea


UNION ALL

SELECT GETDATE(),NULL,'','*****TOTAL *****','','',SUM([Total importe]) FROM (
select 
[Fecha factura],
[Numero factura], 
Paciente as [Paciente], 
Cliente as [Cliente], 
Tarifa,
Servicio,
[Total importe]

from VLISE_Cobros_por_linea


) AS TraspasoTotalizados
Group by [Numero factura]
ORDER BY [Fecha factura] asc--, [Numero factura] ASC, [Total importe] DESC

SELECT * FROM @tbTemp
```

Este es el resultado que obtengo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

[image: El resultado que actumante obtengo con el query es el siguiente]

Trate de ordenar de distintas formas pero siempre me da el mismo problema no consigo agregar la fila exactamente abajo del final de cada grupo de facturas.

Comment: esa tabla se ve bien.. eso es lo que queres lograr y no podes?

Comment: Es correcto ese resultado necesito realizar pero el que obtengo ahora es totalmente distinto ya que suma los totales pero las cada fila de ***TOTAL*** las agrega hasta abajo o arriba todas juntas depende del order by

Comment: Entiendo que quieres el total de cada factura en una sola fila, como se muestra el total del importe de cada servicio? De ser así, se puede hacer solo que si pintas un detalle así como lo estas haciendo ahorita, ese total factura, se pintara repetidamente por cada línea detalle de tu reporte. Si quieres una sola línea, tienes que mostrar únicamente, el número de factura, fecha y cliente (que son los mismos datos para todo el detalle), pero si agregas descripción de servicio, esto romperá la agrupación, por ende te devolverá más de una línea por factura.

Answer (score 0):

Para que los totales queden debajo de cada factura y como estarías ordenando finalmente por fecha y factura, la fila de totales debería heredar estas dos columnas. Por último, para asegurarnos que los totales sea la última fila de cada grupo, deberíamos definir una columna "ad-hoc" para poder agregarla al orden:

```
select  [Fecha factura],
        [Numero factura], 
        Paciente as [Paciente], 
        Cliente as [Cliente], 
        Tarifa,
        Servicio,
        [Total importe],
        1 AS Orden
        from VLISE_Cobros_por_linea

UNION ALL

select  [Fecha factura],
        [Numero factura], 
        '',
        '*****TOTAL *****', 
        '', 
        '', 
        SUM([Total importe]),
        2 AS Orden
        from VLISE_Cobros_por_linea
        Group by [Fecha factura], [Numero factura]

ORDER BY [Fecha factura], [Numero factura], Orden
```

Comentarios:

- Como puedes ver, quitamos la subconsulta en los totales ya que no es realmente necesaria
- Definimos la columna `Orden`, la llenamos con 1 para todas las filas de detalle y 2 para los totales
- Por último ordenamos por `[Fecha factura], [Numero factura], Orden`

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio de mucho